# What visa do I need to volunteer in the US if I am Canadian and only going to volunteer?

Tags: usa, canadian-citizens

I am planning on traveling to the USA to volunteer at a non-profit organization for roughly 6 months. Do I need to get a visa to do so and if I do, which one do I need? I am a Canadian citizen and I will not be getting paid for my work being done there.

Comment: Is the organization going to sponsor you for a J-1 visa? The B-visas do not allow you to work ([paid or otherwise](https://de.usembassy.gov/unpaid-work-is-work-make-sure-you-have-the-correct-visa/)).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas volunteer activities that are normally performed by volunteers [are not considered work](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/47956/19400), however, so it depends on what specific voluntary activities are planned.  Nicole, what kind of volunteering are you planning to do?

Comment: For six months I'm rather doubting it's the kind of exempt volunteer activity. Woofing isn't exempt.